# Solr - cant query special characters or numbers

Tags: solr

In the solr field PackageTag

```
<field name="PackageTag" type="text_en_splitting" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" multiValued="true"/>
```

I have the following value

```
"playing @@*"
```

now I am searcing for "play" i get it in my result.
But when I am searching with @@* i do not.
It is omitted in the word delimiter.

Is there a way i can let the user search upon its special caharacters but still use word delimiting?

Answer (score 1):

There are twoissues here:

- first off, you must create your own fieldType in Solr and configure it to NOT user "@" and "*" as stopWords:

in schema.xml do something like this:

```
<types>
        <fieldType name="myTextFieldType" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
            <analyzer type="index">
                <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory" />
                <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true"
                    words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
            </analyzer>
            <analyzer type="query">
                <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory" />             
                <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true"
                    words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
            </analyzer>
        </fieldType>
        </types>
```

You must then use that fieldType for the "PackageTag" field:

```
<field name="PackageTag" type="text_en_splitting"
```

- Then, in the "conf" dir (the same dir where schema.xml is located), create or edit the stopwords.txt file and add "@" and "*" to it. Just put them in there, each character on one line:

  @

  *

Now, since the "`*`" character is also a special character for Lucene queries (wildcard), you need to escape it in your queries. You can escape "`*`" by replacing it with "`\*`". Something like this:

```
PackageTag:bla\*
```

to search for fields containing "bla*".

Answer (score 0):

I don't recall the list of Lucene special characters, but did you try escaping with a `\` (back slash) before the character?

If that doesn't work, you might want to take a look at the `Analyzer` you are using to index your fields. `StandardAnalyzer` might do something funny with your special characters, so you could consider another analyzer or roll your own.

Comment: For completness, here's the complete list of Lucene special chars: http://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/queryparsersyntax.html#Escaping%20Special%20Characters

Answer (score 0):

You have to add your word delimiter chars in the protwords.txt file and then apply a filter that use the protwords at indexation and query time. (for example `solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory` with the `protected="protwords.txt"` parameter).

In this way they will be tokenized as you want and not removed during query time.